# PubNub PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, pubnub

I am using PubNub SDK for chat in my application. I have created global object of `PubNub *client`.

I subscribes user to multiple channel. It is working fine in normal scenario. But when I am chatting with someone and I lock the phone and unlock again `[client channels]` returns emtpy array and I received `PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory`. But if I subscribed to multiple channel and just goes to background and again in foreground then it is working fine in both scenario same log printed. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Good description thank you for the details.

Comment: @PubNub Hope I will get some solution here.

Comment: Have you sent a note on support@pubnub.com help desk?  I've forwarded your posting too.

Comment: yes I have forwarded there. Hope I will get solutions soon from team.

Comment: You should hear back from us today on this. And we'll post answer here as well.

Comment: @CraigConover Any update?

Comment: I guess no one reviewed this. Can you send email to support@pubnub.com with attached log that captures this behavior? [To enable logging, see our Objective-C SDK Troubleshooting Docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pubnub-objective-c-sdk-v4-troubleshooting-guide)?

Comment: The PubNub platform and their developer support is pretty lousy…but this StackOverflow thread helped me. I was receiving the same PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory errors as @vivek here until I removed spaces from my UUID. How does the PubNub SDK not catch this or provide *any* feedback?